# Link to a static file from Hamlet

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm currently experimenting with Yesod by following the [tutorial on the Yesod Wiki](http://www.yesodweb.com/wiki/yesod_tutorial/filling_in_the_layout).

First I created a yesod application using `yesod init`, and created a Root handler that renders a widget file called `homepage`:

```
getRootR = do
mu <- maybeAuth
defaultLayout $ do
    h2id <- lift newIdent
    setTitle "Home"
    addWidget $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

I have an image file in the static directory call `static/img/logo.png`

After touching `Settings/staticFiles.hs`, I successfully managed to link this file from `default-layout.hamlet` via

```
<img src=@{StaticR img_logo_png}
```

The problem occurs now that I want to include this static file in my `homepage` widget, using exactly the same line of code. The following error occurs at compilation:

```
Handler/Root.hs:19:21:
    Not in scope: `img_logo_png'
    In the result of the splice:
      $(widgetFile "homepage")
    To see what the splice expanded to, use -ddump-splices
    In the first argument of `addWidget', namely
      `$(widgetFile "homepage")'
    In the expression: addWidget ($(widgetFile "homepage"))
```

So my question is: how do I link static resources in widgets defined with `widgetFile`, and why does it behave differently in the default layout template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an import to Handler/Root.hs:

```
import Settings.StaticFiles
```

If a hamlet file requires it then whichever handler.hs file that calls that hamlet file will need to import it first.  The reason why default-layout.hamlet doesn't require any changes is because it is called somewhere in I believe Application.hs which has imports for pretty much everything, including static stuff.