# How to link to a static file in Hamlet?

Tags: haskell, yesod, static-files, hamlet

I looked at [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824915/link-to-a-static-file-from-hamlet) that sounds like it’s the same question, but it seems to skip over a part that I must be missing.

I added the `import Settings.StaticFiles` line at the top of the handler file.

I copied a file called `chunk.png` into the `static` folder of the yesod project.

However, no matter what I try, I always get:

> Not in scope: 'chunk_png'

I’ve tried adding `staticSite "static"` or `$(staticSite "static")` before the whamlet, but to no avail.

Here’s the full code:

```
module Handler.Foo where

import Import
import Data.List
import Settings.StaticFiles

getFooR :: Int -> Int -> Handler Html
getFooR param1 param2 = do
    staticSite "static"
    defaultLayout [whamlet|
        <img src=@{StaticR chunk_png}>
    |]
```

I’ve also tried `staticFiles "static"` (instead of `staticSite`) but that gives me the error:

> Not in scope: 'staticFiles' Perhaps you meant 'staticSite' (imported from Settings.StaticFiles)

There **is** an entry for `/static StaticR Static getStatic` in `config/routes`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me was to add

```
import Yesod.Static
```

at the top of the file, and

```
staticFiles "static"
```

**before** the handler function declaration, rather than inside of it.